# iOS UITableView cells getting duplicated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableviewcontroller that has dynamic controls created in cells. If it's a dropdown type, I take the user to a different tableviewcontroller to select the value. Once selected, I pop back and reload the data, but when I do that it overwrites the cells on top of one another. I know this is because I'm reusing the cells, but I cannot seem to figure out how to prevent it.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    EWHInboundCustomAttribute *ca = [visibleCustomAttributes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.tag=indexPath.row;


    if (ca.CustomControlType == 1) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.hidden=true;
        cell.textLabel.hidden=true;

        UITextField *caTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 185, 30)];

            caTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            caTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            caTextField.placeholder = ca.LabelCaption;
            if (ca.ReadOnly) {
                [caTextField setEnabled: NO];
            } else {
                [caTextField setEnabled: YES];
            }
            caTextField.text=nil;
            caTextField.text=ca.Value;
            caTextField.tag=indexPath.row;

            caTextField.delegate=self;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:caTextField];



    } else if (ca.CustomControlType == 4) {

        cell.detailTextLabel.text=ca.Value;
        cell.textLabel.text=ca.LabelCaption;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    } else {

            cell.detailTextLabel.hidden=true;
            cell.textLabel.hidden=true;
            UITextField *caTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 185, 30)];
            caTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            caTextField.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

            caTextField.placeholder = ca.LabelCaption;
            [caTextField setEnabled: NO];
            caTextField.text = ca.Value;

            caTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
            caTextField.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:caTextField];
    }



    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: To improve performance, cells are reused. That's why your cell contains content that was displayed before. I would suggest googling something like "uitableviewcell reuse" and get a good idea of how it works.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yes, I agree about reusing cells. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to update the uitextfield instead of create it again.

Comment: You cannot do this :  [cell.contentView addSubview:caTextField]; and  [cell.contentView addSubview:caTextField]; Use IB to add them for you. You can give cells with different Identifiers : @"cell", @"cell1", @"cell2" etc, to directly load cells from IB but adding subviews by yourself.

Comment: @E.Coms could you expand on this please? I don't understand what you mean by add different identifiers.

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]; This give you one kind of cell. if (ca.CustomControlType == 1) {UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]; } else if (ca.CustomControlType == 4) {UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1"]; }else{UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2"]; } You can add three kinds of cell prototypes in your IB and  in their identifiers .

Comment: You should **never** manipulate the view hierarchy of any cell. Instead design different cells, registered under different identifiers.

Comment: @Cristik So if I create a new cell with a textfield, how can i reference that textfield to update it? Especially since I will have multiple cell of that type?

Comment: @btorkelson as I recommended in my last comment, use different cells, having different classes that expose the textfields or other controls you need.

Comment: Use tag for each ui. Cell.viewwithtag() to refer textfield

Comment: @E.Coms what an 80's way to program, using tags. We have OOP now, we can add properties on classes.

Comment: @Cristik So do I need to design different cells in the IB or create different classes for each type?

Comment: @btorkelson different classes, with our without xibs by your preference. But definitively different classes and different tableView identifiers.

Comment: @btorkelson you may check this out: https://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Follow this example and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the UITextfield each time I would suggest at least using `[UIView viewWithTag:tag]` to capture the same UITextField object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to create custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and put all subviews related logic there.
Next, in order to reset/clear cell before reuse - you should override `prepeareForReuse` function.

Swift:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    //set cell to initial state here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First,I suggest you to use custom cells.If not and your cells are not so many,maybe you can try unique cell identifier to avoid cell reuse:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // unique reuseID
    NSString *cellReuseID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld_%ld", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellReuseID];
        // do something
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Hope it's helpful.